# Как настроить сервер на http? Он работает только на https запросы (https://instinctbalance.ru/)

Tags: nginx

Само приложение запущено на 443 порту. Вот конфигурация сервера nginx

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name www.instinctbalance.ru instinctbalance.ru;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443;
  listen [::]:443;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/instinctbalance.ru.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/instinctbalance.ru.key;

  server_name instinctbalance.ru www.instinctbalance.ru;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Comment: Что значит «не работает»?

Comment: Страница не загружается по адресу http://instinctbalance.ru/

Comment: Перезагрузить nginx. Проверить настройки файрволла

Comment: А не может быть такого, что в самом приложении форсится ипользование https? Судя по конфигу Nginx - приложение должно отвечать и по 443=му, и по 80-му пору. В любом случае, у Вас в руках больше инструментов диагностики - telnet, например :-)